# Export & Link a Local Table to a Backend DB?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Local table (Table_A) that I want to periodically export/copy to a backend database as (Table_A_Snap).  Each subsequent snapshot will overwrite prior snapshots.

The following snippet produces the following result:

1. Table_A_Snap is created in the Local DB
2. Table_A_Snap also created in the Backend DB
3. The desired LINK to the Backend table is not produced
4. Note:  As the code runs I can actually momentarily see Table_A_Snap appear as a LINKED tale, but then it converts to a Local Table (no link)
5. TempVars!my_path = full path to backend DB

Snippet:

```
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", TempVars!my_path, acTable, "Table_A", "Table_A_Snap", -1

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", TempVars!my_path, acTable, "Table_A_Snap", "Table_A_Snap"
```

I am guessing this is a simple syntax issue.  Any suggestions to remedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - Bonehead issue - I copied over the newly created LINKED table further down into code - Apologies! :)